# Using different Datasources for different configurations in SSRS

Tags: deployment, configuration, reporting-services, datasource

I'm wondering if it's possible for SSRS reports to use different datasources depending on what configuration is being used?
So, for example, if I'm using the 'DebugLocal' configuration, the reports would use a different database than if I'm using the 'Production' configuration.
Thanks
Bryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Report Designer, the simplest way to do this would be to edit the shared datasource immediately prior to running the report.

In Report Manager, you can achieve this by having the same datasource pointing to different databases in different folders (eg. one folder for DebugLocal, another for Production), and deploying and running the report in the appropriate folder.

Comment: +1, different datasources in different folders is the easiest option for this.